# Lack of tags and mobile site problems

Tags: support, tags

Why can't I crate new tags on Mobile?

And why isn't there a tag about pyrokinetics in over twenty thousand question. And I noticed lack of tags before that to. Like There isn't any tag about mobile site in the meta too.
I can't use some of the other features that are  in the desktop site too.
I am pretty sure this are problems with stackexchange itself. But I still think lack of tags is a fundamental and easy to solve problems.

(And I know I can open desktop site in Mobile but that doesn't mean there isn't a problem).

Comment: I just created a mobile-site tag here on meta and added it to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cover all three of your questions:

### No mobile tag & adding tags

The reason for no mobile tag on WB.SE is because this stack cannot do anything about the mobile app and therefore have limited questions about mobile (i.e. nobody has actually asked one and thereby created the tag). Though you can ask here, typically questions about mobile should be taken to the Main Meta for Stack Exchange unless they are a specific issue with the sub-site (for example: MathJax rendering on Math.SE would be asked on Math.SE's meta over the Main one).

In fact, there is a [question on Meta about this exact issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags-with-mobile-app?rq=1) so you may want to add a new answer there or create a bounty for more attention.

Also note: the mobile app is not well supported (Google even [dropped the SO one due to lack of development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-app-for-android)) and the current answer by SE seems to be "we're moving to responsive websites so we won't need an app".

### Pyro tag

I would open a new question about that stating your case as currently I don't see a situation where we couldn't just use [super-powers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-powers), [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) or [supernatural](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supernatural), or a science based tag (nano, bio, etc) depending on why the person has pyrokinesis.

I'll note, in that vein, that the [pyro tag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyrokinetics) you made on your question should just be [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic). It will also likely be deleted (automatically) if it is not used again within 6 months and - after a quick search - this is only the third or fourth questions dealing with pyrokinetics since the site started and the others all used magic, super-powers, or technology.

Comment: Thanks for clarification I am new to the stackexchange thing and I wasn't aware of stackexchange meta. I was able to solve my problem with using desktop site. My problem was about lack of specific tags. And I can understand why they aren't there. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's ok to ask support questions (or report bugs) here.  Questions will get more attention on main meta, but I understand that developers do monitor these tags on per-site metas too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yeah, I should (and have) edit that - I meant it more in the "because mobile questions are typically asked on Main so nobody had created one/raised a question to this point" more than you have to ask on Main (though in this case its on Main and the answer is the same with every mobile question - "not a priority" or just silence).

Answer (score 2):

### Why is there no [pyrokinetics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyrokinetics) tag?  Because it's not needed.

If we had lots of questions on this topic, it would be reasonable to create a tag for it.  So far, we have [6 questions with the keyword pyrokinetics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=pyrokinetics%20is%3Aq) and at least 1 or 2 of them would not warrant the tag (as it isn't the focus of the question).

We already have a tag for [fire](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire), which isn't the same, but has some similar elements.  And we have [super-powers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-powers).  Put those two together and you get [pyrokinetics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyrokinetics).

Also, please do not create new tags without discussing it here on Meta and getting a consensus.

Comment: I get the point in the last answer. I am not totally aware of how site work. That's why I asked that question now I won't create tags without discussion.